# WebMvcTest attempts to load every application Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-test-mvc

When I try to implement a WebMvcTest it attempts to instantiate every application controller rather than just the one indicated on the `@WebMvcTest` annotation.

Without any luck or success, I've read these articles:

- [Spring Boot Testing @WebMvcTest for a Controller appears to load other controllers in the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512074/spring-boot-testing-webmvctest-for-a-controller-appears-to-load-other-controlle)
- [@WebMvcTest fails with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078044/webmvctest-fails-with-java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-load-applicati)
- [@WebMvcTest creating more than one Controller for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078125/webmvctest-creating-more-than-one-controller-for-some-reason)
- [Test slice with @WebMvcTest is loading a substantial amount of controllers unrelated with the target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224814/test-slice-with-webmvctest-is-loading-a-substantial-amount-of-controllers-unrel)

And here are the parts of my code that I found relevant

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/complaints/{id}/comments")
public class CommentController {

  @PostMapping
  public CommentJson comment(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody CommentCommand command) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented yet");
  }
}
```

```java
@WebMvcTest(CommentController.class)
class CommentControllerTest extends AbstractTest {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;
  // ...
}
```

When I run the tests it fails with the following error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.company.package.controller.ComplaintController required a bean of type 'com.company.package.service.Complaints' that could not be found.
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/complaints")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ControllerAdvice()
public class ComplaintController {
  private final Complaints complaints;

  // ... other controller methods

  @ExceptionHandler(ComplaintNotFoundException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Void> handleComplaintNotFoundException() {
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  }
}
```

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public abstract class AbstractTest {
  private final Faker faker = new Faker();

  protected final Faker faker() {
    return faker;
  }

  // ... other utility methods
}
```

The only way I found to make my Web Mvc Tests run is to mock every dependency of each controller on all `@WebMvcTest` which is very tedious.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please add the code for your `AbstractTest` class

Comment: @rieckpil I've updated and included the `AbstractTest` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While taking a close look at your `ComplaintController`, you annotate it with `@ControllerAdvice`

The Javadoc of `@WebMvcTest` says the following about the relevant MVC beans that are part of the Spring Context for your test:

```
/**
 * Annotation that can be used for a Spring MVC test that focuses <strong>only</strong> on
 * Spring MVC components.
 * <p>
 * Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only
 * configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. {@code @Controller},
 * {@code @ControllerAdvice}, {@code @JsonComponent},
 * {@code Converter}/{@code GenericConverter}, {@code Filter}, {@code WebMvcConfigurer}
 * and {@code HandlerMethodArgumentResolver} beans but not {@code @Component},
 * {@code @Service} or {@code @Repository} beans).
 * ...
 */
```

So any `@ControllerAdvice` is part of this MVC context and hence that's the expected behaviour.

To fix this you could extract your exception handling out of your `ComplaintController` into a dedicated class that does depend on any other Spring Beans and can be instantiated without mocking anything.

PS: The word **all** is misleading inside the title of your question *WebMvcTest attempts to load every application Controller*.

Comment: That's what I was missing, it worked like a charm, thanks.